# xdrc 'cpp.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: stellar-core

I am trying to build stellar-core on Windows. I have followed the instructions in the windows install markdown but I am getting the error below.

Error MSB6006 "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. stellar-core

could anyone help me out the reason for this

Adding more info:
Log info from output console:

2>------ Build started: Project: stellar-core, Configuration: DebugNoPostgres x64 ------
2>running xdrc
2>'cpp.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2>operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

In the markdown documentation, the below line should also tell you to choose GCC and sed

In the MinGW Installation Manager in MSYS/MinGW Developer Toolkit choose Flex and Bison packages for installation